# Lucene 4.9: During Indexing add Sentiment to sentences

Tags: lucene, tokenize, analyzer, sentence

I have a `SentimentAttribute` class which extends `AttributeImpl`. Also I am currently writing a `SentenceSentimentTaggingFilter` class which should

1. take `InputStream` (consisting of text)
2. tokenize it into *sentences*
3. assign a sentiment to each sentence, i.e., by adding `SentimentAttribute` to it

The problem I currently have is that it seems like there is only functionality inside Lucene which tokenizes text into individual tokens, e.g., single words, but nothing to split into sentences.

What is the best way to integrate this with a regular `EnglishAnalyzer` I'm also using during indexing? I would like to avoid to process both `EnglishAnalyzer` and my analysis in parallel but rather *hook in* my analysis in between the processing steps of the `EnglishAnalyzer` (assuming that this is the fastest / most efficient way).

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually doing something very similar but in an earlier version of Lucene, V3.0.2. You may want to look at the following class:

`org.apache.lucene.wordnet.AnalyzerUtil`

Although you've probably found a way to do this by now. I hope it might help anyway.